# text section exceeds available space in board

Tags: esp32, error

When I compile this code it gives the error mentioned above.
I saw online a way to resolve this: `Serial.println(F("..."));`

For fixed string literal I changed it but still didn't work.
I'm compiling this for ESP32 board.

```
#include "RMaker.h"
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "WiFiProv.h"
#include <DHT.h>
#include <SimpleTimer.h>

const char *service_name = "PROV_SmartHome";
const char *pop = "1234";

// define the Chip Id
uint32_t espChipId = 5;

// define the Node Name
char nodeName[] = "ESP32_Smarthome";

// define the Device Names
char deviceName_1[] = "Switch1";
char deviceName_2[] = "Switch2";
char deviceName_3[] = "Switch3";
char deviceName_4[] = "Switch4";

// define the GPIO connected with Relays and switches
static uint8_t RelayPin1 = 23;  //D23
static uint8_t RelayPin2 = 22;  //D22
static uint8_t RelayPin3 = 21;  //D21
static uint8_t RelayPin4 = 19;  //D19

static uint8_t SwitchPin1 = 13;  //D13
static uint8_t SwitchPin2 = 12;  //D12
static uint8_t SwitchPin3 = 14;  //D14
static uint8_t SwitchPin4 = 27;  //D27

static uint8_t wifiLed      = 2;   //D2
static uint8_t gpio_reset   = 0;
static uint8_t DHTPIN       = 18; // D18  pin connected with DHT
static uint8_t LDR_PIN      = 39; // VN  pin connected with LDR

/* Variable for reading pin status*/
// Relay State
bool toggleState_1 = LOW; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 1
bool toggleState_2 = LOW; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 2
bool toggleState_3 = LOW; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 3
bool toggleState_4 = LOW; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 4

// Switch State
bool SwitchState_1 = LOW;
bool SwitchState_2 = LOW;
bool SwitchState_3 = LOW;
bool SwitchState_4 = LOW;

float temperature1 = 0;
float humidity1   = 0;
float ldrVal  = 0;

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHT11);  //For DHT 11
//DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHT22);  //For DHT 22

SimpleTimer Timer;

//The framework provides some standard device types like switch, lightbulb, fan, temperature sensor.
static Switch my_switch1(deviceName_1, &RelayPin1);
static Switch my_switch2(deviceName_2, &RelayPin2);
static Switch my_switch3(deviceName_3, &RelayPin3);
static Switch my_switch4(deviceName_4, &RelayPin4);
static TemperatureSensor temperature("Temperature");
static TemperatureSensor humidity("Humidity");
static TemperatureSensor ldr("LDR");

void sysProvEvent(arduino_event_t *sys_event)
{
  switch (sys_event->event_id) {
    case ARDUINO_EVENT_PROV_START:
#if CONFIG_IDF_TARGET_ESP32
      Serial.printf("\nProvisioning Started with name \"%s\" and PoP \"%s\" on BLE\n", service_name, pop);
      printQR(service_name, pop, "ble");
#else
      Serial.printf("\nProvisioning Started with name \"%s\" and PoP \"%s\" on SoftAP\n", service_name, pop);
      printQR(service_name, pop, "softap");
#endif
      break;
    case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_CONNECTED:
      Serial.printf("\nConnected to Wi-Fi!\n");
      digitalWrite(wifiLed, true);
      break;
  }
}

void write_callback(Device *device, Param *param, const param_val_t val, void *priv_data, write_ctx_t *ctx)
{
  const char *device_name = device->getDeviceName();
  const char *param_name = param->getParamName();

  if (strcmp(device_name, deviceName_1) == 0) {

    Serial.printf("Lightbulb = %s\n", val.val.b ? "true" : "false");

    if (strcmp(param_name, "Power") == 0) {
      Serial.printf("Received value = %s for %s - %s\n", val.val.b ? "true" : "false", device_name, param_name);
      toggleState_1 = val.val.b;
      (toggleState_1 == false) ? digitalWrite(RelayPin1, HIGH) : digitalWrite(RelayPin1, LOW);
      param->updateAndReport(val);
    }

  } else if (strcmp(device_name, deviceName_2) == 0) {

    Serial.printf("Switch value = %s\n", val.val.b ? "true" : "false");

    if (strcmp(param_name, "Power") == 0) {
      Serial.printf("Received value = %s for %s - %s\n", val.val.b ? "true" : "false", device_name, param_name);
      toggleState_2 = val.val.b;
      (toggleState_2 == false) ? digitalWrite(RelayPin2, HIGH) : digitalWrite(RelayPin2, LOW);
      param->updateAndReport(val);
    }

  } else if (strcmp(device_name, deviceName_3) == 0) {

    Serial.printf("Switch value = %s\n", val.val.b ? "true" : "false");

    if (strcmp(param_name, "Power") == 0) {
      Serial.printf("Received value = %s for %s - %s\n", val.val.b ? "true" : "false", device_name, param_name);
      toggleState_3 = val.val.b;
      (toggleState_3 == false) ? digitalWrite(RelayPin3, HIGH) : digitalWrite(RelayPin3, LOW);
      param->updateAndReport(val);
    }

  } else if (strcmp(device_name, deviceName_4) == 0) {

    Serial.printf("Switch value = %s\n", val.val.b ? "true" : "false");

    if (strcmp(param_name, "Power") == 0) {
      Serial.printf("Received value = %s for %s - %s\n", val.val.b ? "true" : "false", device_name, param_name);
      toggleState_4 = val.val.b;
      (toggleState_4 == false) ? digitalWrite(RelayPin4, HIGH) : digitalWrite(RelayPin4, LOW);
      param->updateAndReport(val);
    }

  }
}

void readSensor() {

  ldrVal = map(analogRead(LDR_PIN), 400, 4200, 0, 100);
  Serial.print("LDR - "); Serial.println(ldrVal);
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature(); // or dht.readTemperature(true) for Fahrenheit

  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
    return;
  }
  else {
    humidity1 = h;
    temperature1 = t;
    Serial.print("Temperature - "); Serial.println(t);
    Serial.print("Humidity - "); Serial.println(h);
  }
}

void sendSensor()
{
  readSensor();
  temperature.updateAndReportParam("Temperature", temperature1);
  humidity.updateAndReportParam("Temperature", humidity1);
  ldr.updateAndReportParam("Temperature", ldrVal);
}

void manual_control()
{
  if (digitalRead(SwitchPin1) == LOW && SwitchState_1 == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin1, LOW);
    toggleState_1 = 1;
    SwitchState_1 = HIGH;
    my_switch1.updateAndReportParam(ESP_RMAKER_DEF_POWER_NAME, toggleState_1);
    Serial.println("Switch-1 on");
  }
  if (digitalRead(SwitchPin1) == HIGH && SwitchState_1 == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin1, HIGH);
    toggleState_1 = 0;
    SwitchState_1 = LOW;
    my_switch1.updateAndReportParam(ESP_RMAKER_DEF_POWER_NAME, toggleState_1);
    Serial.println("Switch-1 off");
  }
  if (digitalRead(SwitchPin2) == LOW && SwitchState_2 == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin2, LOW);
    toggleState_2 = 1;
    SwitchState_2 = HIGH;
    my_switch2.updateAndReportParam(ESP_RMAKER_DEF_POWER_NAME, toggleState_2);
    Serial.println("Switch-2 on");
  }
  if (digitalRead(SwitchPin2) == HIGH && SwitchState_2 == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin2, HIGH);
    toggleState_2 = 0;
    SwitchState_2 = LOW;
    my_switch2.updateAndReportParam(ESP_RMAKER_DEF_POWER_NAME, toggleState_2);
    Serial.println("Switch-2 off");
  }
  if (digitalRead(SwitchPin3) == LOW && SwitchState_3 == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin3, LOW);
    toggleState_3 = 1;
    SwitchState_3 = HIGH;
    my_switch3.updateAndReportParam(ESP_RMAKER_DEF_POWER_NAME, toggleState_3);
    Serial.println("Switch-3 on");
  }
  if (digitalRead(SwitchPin3) == HIGH && SwitchState_3 == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin3, HIGH);
    toggleState_3 = 0;
    SwitchState_3 = LOW;
    my_switch3.updateAndReportParam(ESP_RMAKER_DEF_POWER_NAME, toggleState_3);
    Serial.println("Switch-3 off");
  }
  if (digitalRead(SwitchPin4) == LOW && SwitchState_4 == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin4, LOW);
    toggleState_4 = 1;
    SwitchState_4 = HIGH;
    my_switch4.updateAndReportParam(ESP_RMAKER_DEF_POWER_NAME, toggleState_4);
    Serial.println("Switch-4 on");
  }
  if (digitalRead(SwitchPin4) == HIGH && SwitchState_4 == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin4, HIGH);
    toggleState_4 = 0;
    SwitchState_4 = LOW;
    my_switch4.updateAndReportParam(ESP_RMAKER_DEF_POWER_NAME, toggleState_4);
    Serial.println("Switch-4 off");
  }
}


void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Set the Relays GPIOs as output mode
  pinMode(RelayPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(wifiLed, OUTPUT);

  // Configure the input GPIOs
  pinMode(SwitchPin1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(SwitchPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(SwitchPin3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(SwitchPin4, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(gpio_reset, INPUT);

  // Write to the GPIOs the default state on booting
  digitalWrite(RelayPin1, !toggleState_1);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin2, !toggleState_2);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin3, !toggleState_3);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin4, !toggleState_4);
  digitalWrite(wifiLed, LOW);
  dht.begin();    // Enabling DHT sensor

  Node my_node;
  my_node = RMaker.initNode(nodeName);

  //Standard switch device
  my_switch1.addCb(write_callback);
  my_switch2.addCb(write_callback);
  my_switch3.addCb(write_callback);
  my_switch4.addCb(write_callback);

  //Add switch device to the node
  my_node.addDevice(my_switch1);
  my_node.addDevice(my_switch2);
  my_node.addDevice(my_switch3);
  my_node.addDevice(my_switch4);
  my_node.addDevice(temperature);
  my_node.addDevice(humidity);
  my_node.addDevice(ldr);

  Timer.setInterval(2000);

  //This is optional
  RMaker.enableOTA(OTA_USING_PARAMS);
  //If you want to enable scheduling, set time zone for your region using setTimeZone().
  //The list of available values are provided here https://rainmaker.espressif.com/docs/time-service.html
  // RMaker.setTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai");
  // Alternatively, enable the Timezone service and let the phone apps set the appropriate timezone
  RMaker.enableTZService();
  RMaker.enableSchedule();

  //Service Name
  for (int i = 0; i < 17; i = i + 8) {
    espChipId |= ((ESP.getEfuseMac() >> (40 - i)) & 0xff) << i;
  }

  Serial.printf("\nChip ID:  %d Service Name: %s\n", espChipId, service_name);

  Serial.printf("\nStarting ESP-RainMaker\n");
  RMaker.start();

  WiFi.onEvent(sysProvEvent);
#if CONFIG_IDF_TARGET_ESP32
  WiFiProv.beginProvision(WIFI_PROV_SCHEME_BLE, WIFI_PROV_SCHEME_HANDLER_FREE_BTDM, WIFI_PROV_SECURITY_1, pop, service_name);
#else
  WiFiProv.beginProvision(WIFI_PROV_SCHEME_SOFTAP, WIFI_PROV_SCHEME_HANDLER_NONE, WIFI_PROV_SECURITY_1, pop, service_name);
#endif

  my_switch1.updateAndReportParam(ESP_RMAKER_DEF_POWER_NAME, false);
  my_switch2.updateAndReportParam(ESP_RMAKER_DEF_POWER_NAME, false);
  my_switch3.updateAndReportParam(ESP_RMAKER_DEF_POWER_NAME, false);
  my_switch4.updateAndReportParam(ESP_RMAKER_DEF_POWER_NAME, false);
}

void loop()
{
  // Read GPIO0 (external button to reset device
  if (digitalRead(gpio_reset) == LOW) { //Push button pressed
    Serial.printf("Reset Button Pressed!\n");
    // Key debounce handling
    delay(100);
    int startTime = millis();
    while (digitalRead(gpio_reset) == LOW) delay(50);
    int endTime = millis();

    if ((endTime - startTime) > 10000) {
      // If key pressed for more than 10secs, reset all
      Serial.printf("Reset to factory.\n");
      RMakerFactoryReset(2);
    } else if ((endTime - startTime) > 3000) {
      Serial.printf("Reset Wi-Fi.\n");
      // If key pressed for more than 3secs, but less than 10, reset Wi-Fi
      RMakerWiFiReset(2);
    }
  }
  delay(100);

  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    //Serial.println("WiFi Not Connected");
    digitalWrite(wifiLed, false);
  }
  else
  {
    //Serial.println("WiFi Connected");
    digitalWrite(wifiLed, true);
    if (Timer.isReady()) {
      //Serial.println("Sending Sensor Data");
      sendSensor();
      Timer.reset();      // Reset a second timer
    }
  }
  manual_control();
}
```

ESP32 Board details here :

[image]

Comment: Are you exceeding program space/flash or RAM? By how much? Have you checked how much space the libraries use?

Comment: @chrisl I don't know how can I check it. I'll look into it.

Comment: When you compile a sketch in the Arduino IDE it will output the amount of used program memory and how much RAM is used by global variables. That gives you a good hint.

Comment: Where is all this text you mentioned? This tiny code should easily fit into the ESP's flash (if you're using `F(...)`)... what flash size does your ESP have? Maybe you can get around it using a different partition scheme.

Comment: Just how large is the compiled program? Could you include the last lines of the compiler output in your question? The tip from @SimSon is also a good one. If you don't need a file system or OTA, you could select a partition scheme that maximizes available code space, like "Huge APP" or  one of the "No OTA" schemes.

Comment: esp32 toolchain uses string literals from flash automatically. the F macro does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I've missed something, but the flash area is partitioned between usable app (roughly sketch code) space and usable filesystem space. I don't see any indication in your question that you're using a filesystem at all.

Keeping your current settings except for switching the partition setting to *"Huge APP (3MB No OTA/1MB SPIFFS)"* resulted in:

```
Sketch uses 1790473 bytes (56%) of program storage space. Maximum is 3145728 bytes.
Global variables use 53260 bytes (16%) of dynamic memory, leaving 274420 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
```

I'm not even sure "Huge APP" makes the *most* sense. Only that 3MB is larger than 1.2MB and larger than your current 1.8(ish)MB build apparently needs. It says "no-OTA" but you don't seem to be using that either. So, this seems like something you can do irrespective of whatever contributions you can trim from the text segment by tweaking your code.

Comment: Partition to Rainmaker I did, its working fine now

Answer (score 1):

You are programming for an embedded processor with limited memory.  Both program space and random access memory (RAM).  Every letter you put in quotes takes up a byte of memory. If you are only over the limit by a little consider abbreviating your text.  For example consider changing strings like:

> "Provisioning Started with name"

... to something along the lines of ...

> "Prov name"

If by a lot then consider changing your code.  Many times you quote similar text. For example consider changing the following code:

```
// define the Device Names
char deviceName_1[] = "Switch1";
char deviceName_2[] = "Switch2";
char deviceName_3[] = "Switch3";
char deviceName_4[] = "Switch4";
...
//The framework provides some standard device types like switch, lightbulb, fan, temperature sensor.
static Switch my_switch1(deviceName_1, &RelayPin1);
static Switch my_switch2(deviceName_2, &RelayPin2);
static Switch my_switch3(deviceName_3, &RelayPin3);
static Switch my_switch4(deviceName_4, &RelayPin4);
```

... to something along the lines of ...

```
//The framework provides some standard device types like switch, lightbulb, fan, temperature sensor.
String stringOne = "Switch";
String stringTwo = "1"
static Switch my_switch1(stringOne + stringTwo, &RelayPin1);
stringTwo = "2"
static Switch my_switch2(stringOne + stringTwo, &RelayPin2);
stringTwo = "3"
static Switch my_switch3(stringOne + stringTwo, &RelayPin3);
stringTwo = "4"
static Switch my_switch4(stringOne + stringTwo, &RelayPin4);
```

... the point here is to avoid using up program and random access memory with repeated strings.

Comment: If any find a problem in the above code or have insight into a more efficient approach please post.  I'll be more than happy to edit the answer to make it better.

Comment: I'll implement these from now on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use enums to replace all the char strings (which take a lot of memory space) into integers behind the scene.

```
enum deviceNames {Switch1, Switch2, Switch3, Switch4};
deviceNames deviceName; //define variable of type deviceNames
```

for comparison you can use:

```
if (deviceName == Switch1); //Switch1 equals 0 for the compiler, Stich2 equals 1 etc etc.
```

Frist however, you should have a look at the functions getDeviceName() and getParamName(). Could you post them? Would need to see if you can make these changes there aswell.
Since you are getting the variable device_name from there, again as a string. Enums would do no good without additional changes to the functions.

*Also I noticed you still didn't use Serial.print(F());
Read up on storing strings and variables into PROGMEM if you're interested.

*EDIT:
As user Juraj noted in the comments: "the esp32 toolchain uses string literals from flash automatically. the F macro does nothing".

Perhaps you can benefit form newlib nano formatting for printf? I'm not sure as I don't know what difference it makes on your esp32 version. You'll have to check out.

Comment: Note that `F()` is meant to save RAM (data section), not flash (text section).

Comment: Yes, as of yet we don't know which of those two memory spaces is exceeded.

Comment: esp32 toolchain uses string literals from flash automatically. the F macro does nothing

Comment: The title of the question says which of those two memory spaces is exceeded.

Comment: @Juraj Aha, that I didn't know. Thanks for noting that.